# I am getting an "unresolved import : PythonMagick" error in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use PythonMagick in my code. The program is supposed to compare two PDF files. I keep getting the red squiggly line at the import line. I am using the latest version of Python, which I think is Python 3.

Did I download the wrong version of ImageMagick? (ImageMagick-7.0.6-9). 
When I compile, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named'PythonMagick'`.

[ImportNotFoundError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SLju.png)

[Unresolved Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Eky.png)

Comment: Perhaps you installed a version for Python 2. Use `pip3` to work with packages for Python 3

Comment: How, (or did you?) install `ImageMagick`? What Operating System are you on (Windows, MacOS, linux)? If you manually downloaded the source, did you build/compile the `ImageMagick` module?

Comment: I am on Windows. I manually downloaded the source. I did not "build/compile" the ImageMagick module. I am not sure how I would do that.

Comment: Is the file you downloaded a Windows executable like `ImageMagick-7.0.6-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe`. At the bottom of ImageMagick's website there are ["Windows Binary Releases"](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php) that do not require any compilation, and the Operating System will install the library. Would you want to try that?

Comment: I wonder if Pythonmagick has been updated for IM 7 compatibility. Sorry, I do not use any API, only the command line, but it might be useful to report your issue to http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/, if you do not resolve it otherwise.

Comment: I downloaded "ImageMagick-7.0.6-9-Q16-x64-dll.exe" and I am still getting the same error. Are you using Python 3.6? DownShift?